# Decoding the wires in a ceiling electrical box in an older home

Tags: electrical

I am installing a ceiling fan in an older house and **want to make sure I have a proper ground**.  I don't trust the wire colors in the box and they have older fabric insulation that may be discolored from age anyway.

I have included a diagram of the wires and a table showing the voltages across all the pairs including the box itself.  The three oval shapes represent the three holes in the box, and the orange shapes are the existing wire connectors.

[For the sake of simplicity in the table I have ignored the wall switch which controls one of the wires (Wire "C").]

*It appears that Wire "B" would be the only candidate for ground because it's the only wire that shows 0 volts relative to the box.  Is that a correct assumption?  If so, is there any other test I can do to verify that "B" is ground?*

I've added a photo which shows the difficulty in identifying clear colors in the wiring.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wire colors are usually actually _very_ important (though not 100% guaranteed). Providing a pic of the actual wiring would be most helpful.

Comment: thanks, photo added.

Comment: Oh, goody! That looks like some of my old wiring! Odds are _really_ good that this is totally ungrounded. Generally speaking, ceiling light fixtures don't need to be grounded since they're very difficult to reach, it's unlikely that a human will get shocked by touching it. (You've got the power off at the switch _and_ breaker, right?)

Comment: Thanks, I never assume someone won't touch a ceiling fan in an 8' ceiling, even if it has a remote, because the pull chain is metal and just generally I think that there's too much at stake to ever risk that.

Comment: Unless that wire is run in metal conduit, it's highly unlikely that there's a ground wire there, and pulling one will be... challenging. _If_ it is in metal conduit, then the conduit itself is likely the ground, but you would need to test to be sure. If it's in conduit, but not currently grounded, you could use the conduit as a ground, assuming that the conduit is continuous and properly connected all the way from the panel or other properly grounded metal box.

Comment: Can one use a DVM (in continuity mode) across the box, and then the ground in a nearby AC outlet (assuming the AC outlet ground is  known good)?

Comment: `DVM` = Digital volt meter? Yes, I believe that either the 2017 or 2020 NEC allows getting a ground from anywhere. You'd have to confirm which version of code is applicable in your locale. Also, wait for an electrician to confirm this. Finally, we're getting yelled at for having a comment conversation, so I'm out... ;)

Comment: I do see metal conduit attached to the box by the way.  I just don't know if it's reliably connected to earth and I don't know where the wire goes.

Comment: Thanks again.  Didn't know comment threads were bad form.  Going with an electrician on this one.

Comment: Using neutral for ground is dangerous, I would recommend not doing that, just do not connect it unless you can run a seperate ground wire. If you get a break in the neutral you can put line voltage on the fixture.

Answer (score 2):

### Wire B is neutral!

With a voltmeter it measures out same as ground, because there's an *equipotential bond* to assure it stays near ground.  But neutral is not ground.

Wiring of that age may not have a ground.  If the wires are in metal conduit (close inspection of the back of the box would reveal that), the metal conduit may carry ground.  Otherwise the installation may pre-date ground.

If you see similar voltage numbers from wires to metal box, and with main breaker off you test continuity beteen neutral and ground, then the box is grounded, or possibly bootlegged somewhere.

Never, ever use neutral for ground (bootlegging).   This will fail in the worst way imaginable.

### Ground is green, yellow w/ green stripe, or bare

If you don't see bare wires in the box, you don't have ground wires.  In the cloth wiring age, ground would be bare since black is not a legal ground color.

In your drawing, you were choosing colors at random for hot and neutral wires.  You picked green for a neutral.  *That was a "faux pas", don't ever do that again*.  Green is sacrosanct and is used only for ground.   That's true pretty much worldwide.

The only other reserved colors are white and gray for neutral.

If you put a considerable load on that circuit (and nothing has been bootlegged), you will see neutral deviate from ground slightly.  The load will cause voltage drop.  People think 0.2% voltage drop will lower the hot wire voltage by 0.2%.  Not at all.  It lowers hot 0.1%, and raises neutral 0.1%. Voltage drop is equal in both wires, because they are the same length.

Comment: Thanks Harper, very helpful!